# Wait until data is downloaded without halting

Tags: ios, objective-c, tcp, wait

I am currently writing a game for the iOS platform. I have come to the point where data about games a logged-in user is participating in is being successfully downloaded from the server, and I am using GCDAsyncSocket for TCP.

Right now I have a view (with a view controller) which is displayed while the data is being downloaded. This view has a loading indicator that spins while data is being downloaded. I also have a button which is initially disabled, but is supposed to be enabled once data is fetched.

Now the question is, how can I make the loading indicator keep spinning, and the button disabled, until the NSArray containing games is filled with the requested number of Game objects? If I do a

```
while([gamesArray count] == 0){
    <do nothing>
}
```

I halt the application, and the loading indicator will not spin at all. If I do an if-check, however, I run the risk that the button which takes the user to the next view is enabled before all games are downloaded... Which leads to a buggy game list.

What is the correct way of doing this? What I want is the indicator to keep spinning, and the button to be disabled, until the array's length is no longer 0 (which means that the AsyncSocket has populated it with objects from the server).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you receive the Game objects using GCDAsyncSocket? You should use the non blocking `- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sender didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag` callback delegate method. Within this callback method you can perform a check if  the gamesArray has the requested number of game objects. If yes you can enable the button and hide the loading indicator.

Comment: There are a dozen different specific schemes, but in general you start the download, disable the appropriate buttons, start the spinner, and then return to the event loop.  When the download completes you get a notification/delegate call which you use to enable the buttons and kill the spinner.

Answer (score 0):

You should show the loading indicator and disable button on the main thread, then call a background thread for downloading data, and then hide the indicator and enable the button on main thread.